# RPM equivalent of pacman -Syu or apt-get update && apt-get upgrade

Tags: terminal, rpm, opensuse

I just recently installed OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, and I have never used rpm based system before. I didnot find any proper guide like Archwiki for such systems.
What terminal command in OpenSUSE would be equivalent to

```
pacman -Syu
```

or

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade
```

in OpenSUSE?

Answer (score 1):

RPM is the Package managing backend like `dpkg` in Ubuntu. OpenSUSE uses `zypper` which is its equivalent for `apt`.

Equivalent of `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade` in OpenSUSE:

```
zypper refresh && zypper update
```